# Java Button size changing when adding html

Tags: java, html, button

I'm just upping my knowledge on GUI and implementation of GUI's and buttons, and I've run into a little issue. I've searched for this, and even compared button codes but nothing seems different from what I'm seeing in comparison to others' code. When I add html to any button, take testOne for instance if I use:

```
JButton testOne = new JButton("<html><b><u>T</u>est<br>1</b></html>");
```

I have a button, of course, but the button is so large with tiny font, while my other buttons are normal size. Anyone have an idea why? I posted the code without a homework tag, because it's not homework, just fun practice.

```
public FunProject(){
    super("Fun Project"); //child
    //create layout and get the content pane for content
    contents = getContentPane();
    contents.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
    leftBox = getContentPane();
    leftBox.setLayout(new BoxLayout(leftBox, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    //menuBar = new 
    //Create the buttons to use
    JButton testOne = new JButton("Test 1");
    JButton testTwo = new JButton("Test 2");
    JButton testThree = new JButton("Test 3");
```

Also, for anyone feeling like spreading a little knowledge, how would I go about stacking my buttons? Right now they're just in a horizontal plane unstacked, but at the location I want (Center to the left). Thank you in advance.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.MenuEvent;
import javax.swing.event.MenuListener;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class FunProject extends JFrame implements ActionListener, KeyListener,     MenuListener{
//Content only visible to me
    private Container contents;
    private Container leftBox;
    private JButton testOne, testTwo, testThree;
    private JMenuBar menuBar;
    private JMenu men, file, edit, exit;
    private JMenuItem fileOpen, fileSave, fileType;
    private JMenuItem editOpen, editSave, editType;


//Constructor
public FunProject(){
    super("Fun Project");
    //create layout and get the content pane for content
    contents = getContentPane();
    contents.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
    leftBox = getContentPane();
    leftBox.setLayout(new BoxLayout(leftBox, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));


    //Key Listener
    this.addKeyListener(this);

    //Creating Menu bar
    menuBar = new JMenuBar();

    //Adding header to menuBar
    men = new JMenu("Test Menu");
    men.addMenuListener(this);
    menuBar.add(men);

    //Adding exit to menuBar
    exit = new JMenu("Exit Menu");
    exit.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_X);
    exit.addMenuListener(this);
    menuBar.add(exit);

    //Add submenu
    file = new JMenu("FILE");
    file.addMenuListener(this);
    men.add(file);

    edit = new JMenu("EDIT");
    edit.addMenuListener(this);
    men.add(edit);

    //Add item to submenu FILE
    fileOpen = new JMenuItem("Open a file");
    fileOpen.addActionListener(this);
    file.add(fileOpen);

    fileSave = new JMenuItem("Save a file");
    fileSave.addActionListener(this);
    file.add(fileSave);

    fileType = new JMenuItem("File type");
    fileType.addActionListener(this);
    file.add(fileType);

    //Add item to submenu EDIT
    editOpen = new JMenuItem("Open a file");
    editOpen.addActionListener(this);
    edit.add(editOpen);

    editSave = new JMenuItem("Save a file");
    editSave.addActionListener(this);
    edit.add(editSave);

    edit = new JMenuItem("File type");
    editType.addActionListener(this);
    edit.add(editType);

    //Add menu bar
    this.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    //Create the buttons to use
    JButton testOne = new JButton("Test 1"); 
    JButton testTwo = new JButton("Test 2");
    JButton testThree = new JButton("Test 3");
    //Button modifications
    testOne.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
    //Add buttons and such to the leftBox (frame > pane)
    leftBox.add(testOne);
    leftBox.add(testTwo);
    leftBox.add(testThree);

    //Tell the program what Listener will handle events for the button or whatever you
    //are implementing
    testOne.addActionListener(this);
    testTwo.addActionListener(this);
    testThree.addActionListener(this);

    //Set size and visibility to display content and color
    setSize(400,300);
    setVisible(true);

}
public static void main(String[] args){
    FunProject fp = new FunProject();
    fp.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

I was messing around with menu's (So ignore the menu code) and what they're all about. That's for later time when I learn it better.

Comment: have you thought about using nested JPanels?

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: `but the button is so large with tiny font,` post your `SSCCE` that demonstrates the problem. The SSCCE should have two buttons one with HTML and the other without so we can see what you are talking about. `how would I go about stacking my buttons?` - what do you mean by stacking?

Comment: Adding a `<b>` and `<br>` is going to change the size of the button (and effect the font), my testing didn't seem to have any issues over that though...

Comment: I'm using newest version of java.
@Camickr how do I go about posting an SSCCE?
By stacking, I mean putting them on top of one another. I'll post the entire code in my EDIT so you can see. 
and to RyanHurling as I mess around with GUI's more, I'm learning the panels and such a bit more.

Comment: `So ignore the menu code` - if the menu code is not relevant to the question then we don't want to see it. A SSCCE should only include code that demonstrates your problem. The code you posted does not compile, so it not close to being a SSCCE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)try to use

> h1 Tag -> `JButton testOne = new JButton("<html><b><u><h1>T</u>est<br>1</b></html>");`

for increase the size or font use `<font>` tag for changing the color or size of the font.

2)some time it depend upon the layout you used check it out

3) try ButtonObject.setBounds();